# grabbing parts out of HTML with Python 3

Tags: html, string, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to format this HTML snippet to my liking.

http://pastebin.com/hwhTLeyk

ignoring ***'s**

I just want the College Forum part,

```
<*strong class="linkBlack">College Forum</strong*>
```

I've tried a lot of things including Regular Expressions and translates, even replace but I can't seem to find a way to pull that Class name out of the HTML

More Code(Grade Grabber 2000): http://pastebin.com/DMzZpZpp

Answer (score 0):

filter(None,re.split()) will do!

```
>>> #st is the input and res is the list
>>> st="""'<strong class="linkBlack">College Forum</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Intro Info Tech</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Earth Science</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Sec. Math 1</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Astronomy</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Computer Tech</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Human Geography H</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">English 9</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Sec. Math 1</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Chess</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">College Forum</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Intro Info Tech</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Earth Science</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Sec. Math 1</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Astronomy</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Computer Tech</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Human Geography H</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">English 9</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Sec. Math 1</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">College Forum</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">A+ Comp Rep/Maint</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Earth Science</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Sec. Math 1</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Aikido</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Exploring Comp Sci</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">World History H</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">English 9</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Sec. Math 1</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">College Forum</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">A+ Comp Rep/Maint</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Earth Science</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Sec. Math 1</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Aikido</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Exploring Comp Sci</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">World History H</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">English 9</strong>, <strong class="linkBlack">Sec. Math 1</strong>'"""
>>> #split the string with comma and for each
>>> #apply the regex filter after stripping the beginning and trailing white space.
>>> res = [filter(None,re.split('(<strong class="linkBlack">)|
(<\/strong*>)',s.strip()))[1] for s in st.split(",")]
['College Forum', 'Intro Info Tech', 'Earth Science', 'Sec. Math 1', 'Astronomy', 'Computer Tech', 'Human Geography H', 'English 9', 'Sec. Math 1', 'Chess', 'College Forum', 'Intro Info Tech', 'Earth Science', 'Sec. Math 1', 'Astronomy', 'Computer Tech', 'Human Geography H', 'English 9', 'Sec. Math 1', 'College Forum', 'A+ Comp Rep/Maint', 'Earth Science', 'Sec. Math 1', 'Aikido', 'Exploring Comp Sci', 'World History H', 'English 9', 'Sec. Math 1', 'College Forum', 'A+ Comp Rep/Maint', 'Earth Science', 'Sec. Math 1', 'Aikido', 'Exploring Comp Sci', 'World History H', 'English 9', 'Sec. Math 1']
```

Hope this helps!